# Action composition in Play framework with Java

Tags: json, security, playframework-2.0

I'm developing a security implementation for Play with composition of actions.

For security reasons sent an access token in the JSON request payload, not in the header of the request.
What I do is, in an action (SecureAction) extract the token and continue with the next action ... As can modify the request in Http.Context?
Some code ..

```
@With(SecureAction.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Secured {
    //TODO ver parametros de acceso ..... al metodo

}

public class SecureAction extends Action.Simple {

    @Override
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        //TODO extract token of request "ctx.request().body()"
        //TODO change request with new body witout token and delegate to the next action
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
 }

 @actions.security.Secured
 public static Result addAccount() {

     Form<Account> f = form(Account.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (f.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest();
        }

        .....
 }
```

Greetings!!!!

Comment: I do not understand your question? What is your question?